# How to make a TouchableOpacity appear at the bottom of my screen once it goes out of view?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and searching for a library that can resolve this issue for me.
I have a TouchableOpacity in the centre of my screen. Now what I want is when the user scrolls up and the TouchableOpacity goes out of view a footer should appear at the bottom of the screen with the same TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite hard to explain it properly, without having a look at your code, but basically what you can do is use react-native ScrollView method onScroll and track the offset of your screen in a function and based on it render or hide the footer like this

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleOffset} />
```

and the function

```
const handleOffset = (event) => {
console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
if(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > yourNumber){
 showFooter()
}else{
 hideFooter()
}
},
```